# View gets pushed up when Personal Hotspot is ON (IOS App - Objective C)

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem but I really have no idea on how to solve it, i'm developing an IOS App using objective-c and whenever Personal Hotspot is turned on the View gets pushed under it (so I lose like 20px of my navigationBar), I tried to found a solution online but I found none, can someone please give me any advice on how to possibly solve this?

**EDIT:**
The problem should be this library that i'm using for the slide menu:
https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu
My root view controller has class SlideNavigationController, I've tried to remove it and the view doesn't get pushed up like before.. Has anyone had a similar issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the slide menu always set `self.view.frame.origin.y` to 0 when it's activated.

To solve this, you need to manually adjust the offset according to the height of the status bar.

There are two places you can find `rect.origin.y = 0` in `SlideNavigationController.m`, one is in `moveHorizontallyToLocation` (it's handling the 'pushing' animation) and the other is in `initialRectForMenu` (the initialization method for the frame). You need to change the `0` to the correct offset for this two lines.

The implementation of calculating the offset can be found [here](https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu/issues/126).

```
- (float)offsetFromTop {
    UIView *view = self.view;
    CGRect statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
    CGRect statusBarWindowRect = [view.window convertRect:statusBarFrame fromWindow:nil];
    CGRect statusBarViewRect = [view convertRect:statusBarWindowRect fromView:nil];
    float fullHeight = statusBarViewRect.size.height;
    float offset = fullHeight;
    if (![UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden) {
        offset -= STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT;
    }
    return offset;
}
```

then replace those two line with `rect.origin.y = [self offsetFromTop];`

Comment: sorry @lozy219 there is just one last "problem", if (for example) the hotspot is ON and I show the menu it calculates the height correct based on the hotspot's bar height, but then if i turn hotspot OFF the menu has an offset from top (the one calculated), is it possible to recalculate the offset?

Comment: @Signo hmm.. I missed this issue before, what about adding ``[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateMenuFrameAndTransformAccordingToOrientation) name:UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification object:nil];`` in the ``setup`` method? when the height of the status bar is changed, we update the menu frame.. however, this might not return you the correct height, need tweaking a bit more. I believe @aryaxt will fix the library soon.

Answer (score 1):

I m also facing same problem, like when i open hotspot my view is going(20 px) down, and if i remove hotspot myview is disturbed (Here i used 3 separate views, like Titlabar, scrollview and bottomview..).

The problem is when you connected to hotspot, at that time "statusbar" height IS increased. So view is pushing down.

Solu: Here based on statusbar height, we are updating the UIView layout, like as below....

In **viewdidload** write below code:

```
-(void)viewdidload
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didStatusBarFrameChanged) name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)didStatusBarFrameChanged
{
CGRect barFrame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;
NSLog(@"didStatusBarFrameChanged %@", NSStringFromCGRect(barFrame));
[self updatePageViewLayouts];
}
```

Note: Here using "**UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification**" this, we are getting statusbar height update Notification.so based on that you can increase/decrease 20px of view size(height).