# Issue of personal hotspot UI Layout in iPhone below X

Tags: ios

My layout is broken when I turn on my personal hotspot but it goes well when  personal hotspot is turned off.

As screen shifts to below portion, it cuts the items when Hotspot bars appear and size of the status bar becomes 40x. I also tried multiple solutions provided here but nothing is working for me.

What I tried and didn't work for me:

1. `Notification Center CGRect newFrame = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"current status bar frame"] CGRectValue];`
2. Code to resize status bar with `willChangeStatusBarFrame`
3. Set Navigation Bar to 'NO'

Comment: Have use used scrollView in your app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Personal Hotspot breaks UI layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537654/personal-hotspot-breaks-ui-layout)

Comment: You may refer to [this](http://studyswift.blogspot.com/2015/12/adjust-ui-components-programmatically.html) tutorial.

Comment: Ya I check with : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537654/personal-hotspot-breaks-ui-layout but that solution doesn't worked in my case .But the issue is same as shared in this post.

I hvnt used scroll view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30610809/6429095
Here is the solution I received after so many efforts and is completely working fine for my code.